# How to add treeview inside dropdownlist in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I am doing jobsite i want the dropdownlist to display the job category like ex(itsoftware) if
the user click that all the IT related information will display below that category
i used treeview control inside dropdownlist. but it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't place anything except `ListItem` into `DropDown` control. Consider to place `TreeView` below the dropdown and update it on `SelectedIndexChanged` dropdown's event. Or use some client-side staff like this one: [mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm#example)